# Block other connection in c3p0 with java

Tags: java, sql-server, c3p0

I'm developping app using java, c3p0 for connection pooling and SQL Server 2005 for database.
My Question is, is there any method to block other connection when we do a transaction in database? For example, if we inserting a record to database, another connection who tried to inserting record on the same table will be waiting until the first is finished succesfully...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the isolation level of your connection for those transactions that require it; the most restrictive is SERIALIZABLE.  You should not try to "block" other connections.

Comment: thanks @duffymo for your answer. That's what i mean, i just don't know the "lock" term, so instead of saying that, use block word. Anyway, thanks again..

Answer (score 0):

You want to lock the table. SQL  server will do this automatically. However you can use query options to control . http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213039(v=sql.80).aspx
Sound like you want an exclusive lock

Exclusive Locks

Exclusive (X) locks prevent access to a resource by concurrent transactions. No other transactions can read or modify data locked with an exclusive (X) lock.